# When does Stack Exchange update rep, badges etc

Tags: discussion

When in the 'day' does Stack Exchange update a users data like reputation, badges etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the main sites, the update is practically instantaneous. On derived sites, including these meta pages and the API pages, there is a lag.  It varies from an hour or two on the meta pages to about a month on the API pages.  (I presume the lag on the API page is intended to make it more difficult to infer specific voting patterns.)

Comment: Thanks Whuber :)